# Calling jQuery callback to manipulate Meteor collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, jquery-events

I'm having issues discerning the fine line between client and server in my Meteor application.

Basically, I'm using a tag plug-in built atop jQuery that fires onAddTag and onRemoveTag functions every time tags are added and removed in a text box.

I want to add and remove the appropriate tags from a Meteor collection every time those callbacks are fired.

How do I do this? Specifically, in relevant HTML file:

```
$('input.tags-input').tagsInput({
    'onAddTag': add_tag,
    'onRemoveTag': remove_tag
});
```

Where do I define the `add_tag` function so that I can update the Tag collection?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want to.

Extreme example:

```
$('input.tags-input').tagsInput({
  'onAddTag': function() {
     Tags.insert({name: 'Foo'});
  },
  'onRemoveTag': function() {
     Tags.remove(this.data('id'));
  },
});
```

Assuming the client has proper privileges to work with the database (allow rules permit it to, or you use `insecure` package), this should work.

Comment: Thanks! I found it most effective to put this code in the template's rendered callback.